# Invoking SAP SOAP Webservice from Salesforce(Callout)

Tags: callout, soap, sap

We have integration from Salesforce to SAP PI where salesforce invokes Soap web service exposed by SAP PI. We received wsdl provided by SAP PI and Apex was generated out of it. Please help in the following two issues that we are facing while connecting to sap pi:

1. How do we provide the credentials(Username, password of SAP PI system) while invoking it from Salesforce? The same were provided as part of Request properties in SOAPUI
2. How do we attach a file while invoking the service? In Soapui it was given under Attachments header.

Please find below the generated Apex from the wsdl that we received:

```
//Generated by wsdl2apex

public class PIService {
    public class DT_SFDC_FIC_Report_Req {
        public PIService.inputdoc_element inputdoc;
        private String[] inputdoc_type_info = new String[]{'inputdoc','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://salesforce.com/FIC','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'inputdoc'};
    }
    public class category_element {
        public PIService.attribute_element[] attribute;
        public String name;
        private String[] attribute_type_info = new String[]{'attribute','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','-1','false'};
        private String[] name_att_info = new String[]{'name'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://salesforce.com/FIC','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'attribute'};
    }
    public class inputdoc_element {
        public PIService.category_element[] category;
        public String location;
        public String title;
        public String file;
        public String mimetype;
        public String createdby;
        public String created;
        public String modified;
        public String description;
        public String correlationid;
        public String source;
        public String Assigned_to_Group;
        public String appuserid;
        public String apppwd;
        public String siteid;
        public String type_x;
        public String action;
        private String[] category_type_info = new String[]{'category','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','-1','false'};
        private String[] location_type_info = new String[]{'location','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] title_type_info = new String[]{'title','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] file_type_info = new String[]{'file','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] mimetype_type_info = new String[]{'mimetype','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] createdby_type_info = new String[]{'createdby','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] created_type_info = new String[]{'created','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] modified_type_info = new String[]{'modified','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] description_type_info = new String[]{'description','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] correlationid_type_info = new String[]{'correlationid','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] source_type_info = new String[]{'source','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] Assigned_to_Group_type_info = new String[]{'Assigned_to_Group','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] appuserid_type_info = new String[]{'appuserid','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apppwd_type_info = new String[]{'apppwd','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] siteid_type_info = new String[]{'siteid','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] type_x_att_info = new String[]{'type'};
        private String[] action_att_info = new String[]{'action'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://salesforce.com/FIC','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'category','location','title','file','mimetype','createdby','created','modified','description','correlationid','source','Assigned_to_Group','appuserid','apppwd','siteid'};
    }
    public class message_element {
        public PIService.node_element node;
        public String statuscode;
        public String statusmessage;
        public String correlationid;
        private String[] node_type_info = new String[]{'node','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] statuscode_type_info = new String[]{'statuscode','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] statusmessage_type_info = new String[]{'statusmessage','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] correlationid_type_info = new String[]{'correlationid','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://salesforce.com/FIC','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'node','statuscode','statusmessage','correlationid'};
    }
    public class item_element {
        public String name;
        private String[] name_att_info = new String[]{'name'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://salesforce.com/FIC','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
    }
    public class attribute_element {
        public String name;
        private String[] name_att_info = new String[]{'name'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://salesforce.com/FIC','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
    }
    public class DT_SFDC_FIC_Report_Resp {
        public PIService.message_element message;
        private String[] message_type_info = new String[]{'message','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://salesforce.com/FIC','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'message'};
    }
    public class node_element {
        public PIService.category_element[] category;
        public String location;
        public String title;
        public String file;
        public String mimetype;
        public String createdby;
        public String created;
        public String modified;
        public String description;
        public String objectid;
        public String type_x;
        public String action;
        private String[] category_type_info = new String[]{'category','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','-1','false'};
        private String[] location_type_info = new String[]{'location','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] title_type_info = new String[]{'title','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] file_type_info = new String[]{'file','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] mimetype_type_info = new String[]{'mimetype','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] createdby_type_info = new String[]{'createdby','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] created_type_info = new String[]{'created','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] modified_type_info = new String[]{'modified','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] description_type_info = new String[]{'description','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] objectid_type_info = new String[]{'objectid','http://salesforce.com/FIC',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] type_x_att_info = new String[]{'type'};
        private String[] action_att_info = new String[]{'action'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://salesforce.com/FIC','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'category','location','title','file','mimetype','createdby','created','modified','description','objectid'};
    }
    public class HTTPS_Port {
        public String endpoint_x = 'XXX Endpoint';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://salesforce.com/FIC', 'PIService'};
        public PIService.message_element SI_SFDC_FIC_Report_OB(PIService.inputdoc_element inputdoc) {
            PIService.DT_SFDC_FIC_Report_Req request_x = new PIService.DT_SFDC_FIC_Report_Req();
            request_x.inputdoc = inputdoc;
            PIService.DT_SFDC_FIC_Report_Resp response_x;
            Map<String, PIService.DT_SFDC_FIC_Report_Resp> response_map_x = new Map<String, PIService.DT_SFDC_FIC_Report_Resp>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1',
              'http://salesforce.com/FIC',
              'MT_SFDC_FIC_Report_Req',
              'http://salesforce.com/FIC',
              'MT_SFDC_FIC_Report_Resp',
              'PIService.DT_SFDC_FIC_Report_Resp'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.message;
        }
    }
}
```

From SOAPUi, the service invokation was successful, PFB the screenshot:

[image]

As you see from the above image,

1. The SAP PI credentials were given under Request properties(highlighted in the screenshot)
2. A pdf is attached under Attchments(next to Headers)(highlighted in the screenshot). The service takes pdf Attachment as input.
3. Expecting a Certificate is provided to Salesforce by PI
   How do we write code for above 3 points while writing callout in Salesforce.

Please let us know how to include code for the above 3 points in the below code for making successful callout:

```
PIService.HTTPS_Port service = new PIService.HTTPS_Port();
PIService.inputdoc_element input = new PIService.inputdoc_element();
PIService.message_element response = new PIService.message_element();
service.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String,String>();
String username = 'SapPIUsername';
String password = 'SapPIPassword';  
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
service.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Authorization',authorizationHeader);
input.siteid='1171';
input.title='abc.pdf';
input.file='abcd.pdf';
input.correlationid='33';
input.mimetype='application/pdf';
input.source='SFDC';
response = service.SI_SFDC_FIC_Report_OB(input);
System.debug(response);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you consuming a WSDL file?

Comment: Yes Carlos, we are consuming wsdl.

Comment: What about the Remote Site Settings? Are they also been entered?Setup-->Security Controls-->Remote Site Settings

Comment: @Jaya Can you share the SAP WSDL? Feel free to change the endpoint that would appear at the end of the file. Also, can you modify your question with the callouts you are using from SoapUI that work. Again, change any credentials that appear there to dummy values.

Comment: Currently the service is being updated from SAP side, I will post it as soon as we receive it, thanks.

Comment: We got updated wsdl and edited my post to include the generated Apex code and other details, please help in making successful callout.

Comment: @DanielBallinger, can you please provide your inputs on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The SAP PI credentials were given under Request properties

This would be flowing through to the Authorization HTTP header. You can do this via the  `inputHttpHeaders_x` on the service proxy class. See [Using Basic Authentication with Web Services](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2009/01/using-basic-authentication-with-web-services.html)

> A pdf is attached under Attchments(next to Headers)(highlighted in the screenshot). The service takes pdf Attachment as input.

SOAP API would be adding the file as a MIME-based attachment. See [Attachments and Inline Files](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html#2-Attachments-and-Inline-Files). As far as I know there is no native support for this via wsdl2apex and the corresponding `WebServiceCallout.invoke` method.

You will need to resort to doing a raw HTTP request from Apex and manually encoding the Content-Type, boundary, etc... This is no easy task in Apex because it doesn't have native support for encoding multipart requests. <strike>I'm currently working on a post about a similar challenge that I'll try and remember to like from here when it is complete.</strike> You can manually build out the multipart/form-data POST body in Apex by carefully handling the Base64 padding characters. See [Steps required to support POSTing multipart/form-data Content-Type from Apex](http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/04/steps-required-to-support-posting.html)

> Expecting a Certificate is provided to Salesforce by PI

See [Using Certificates with SOAP Services](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_client_certs_soap.htm)

Comment: Thanks Dan for your response, I will convey the same to the SAP PI team that it is complex to send pdf as MIME-based attachment from SFDC. Please let me know if there any other (easy) way for SFDC to send pdf files to external system so that we can ask SAP PI team to modify their web service accordingly.  Thanks again Dan.

Comment: Please let us know if it is possible to send MIME-based attachment if the external system uses REST instead of SOAP..  i.e. If external system exposes REST service which expects Mime-based Attachment(pdf in this case) then is it possible from Salesforce to invoke that external REST service providing MIME-based attachment? Thanks.

Comment: @Jaya Yes, it is possible because I just did it against the REST based Salesforce Predictive Vision Service. See [Steps required to support POSTing multipart/form-data Content-Type from Apex](http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/04/steps-required-to-support-posting.html)

Comment: I will go through the link that you sent, thanks Dan for quick response.

Comment: I tried to invoke the SAP web service using code updated in OP but getting an error called "Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':html'". Please let me know if I am giving SAP PI credentials properly using inputHttpHeaders_x. Thanks.

Comment: @Jaya you will need to check the HTML response that is coming back to get the full details. Check the CALLOUT_RESPONSE in a developer edition debug log.